# What would be the equivalent to the Windows API CreateEvent function in C#

Tags: c#, c++

I have an example for cross-thread event signalling in C++.

```
HANDLE WriteCompleted = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);

SetEvent(WriteCompleted);
WaitForSingleObject(pThis->WriteCompleted, INFINITE);
CloseHandle(WriteCompleted);
```

1. If *SetEvent()* sets the event, then what clears that event? Does *WaitForSingleObject()* clears this event on return?
2. What would be the approach to implement the same idea using C#?

Comment: Take a look at `WaitHandle`, it should be somewhat similar to what you are trying to do. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle(v=vs.110).aspx or `ManualResetEvent` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is not so much *event handling* as it is *process synchronization*. The documentation is a good place to start.

Comment: You created an auto-reset event, second argument to CreateEvent().  So simply waiting for it with WaitForSingleObject() is enough to reset it.  Otherwise you'd consider ResetEvent().  Neither matters if you use the event for just one event, like you do here.  Which is common.  .NET has AutoResetEvent, does the *exact* same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent in C# can be accomplished with a `ManualResetEvent`.

```
using(var WriteCompleted = new ManualResetEvent(false))
{
   WriteCompleted.Set(); //causes threads blocked on WaitOne() to proceed
   WriteCompleted.WaitOne(); //waits until the event is signaled
   WriteCompleted.Reset(); //causes threads to block on WaitOne() call
}
```

You can also use `AutoResetEvent`, which automatically calls `Reset` after `Set`. The event you created in your sample code sets bManualReset to `FALSE` indicating that this event more closely emulates an `AutoResetEvent`.

No matter how you end up implementing it, don't forget to call `Dispose()` on the object at some point. `Dispose()` is implicitly called in the sample when the `using` block goes out of scope.

[MSDN for ManualResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx)

[MSDN for AutoResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here is a more concrete sample usage of AutoResetEvent:

```
private static AutoResetEvent m_event = new AutoResetEvent(false);

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
   new Thread(() =>
   {
      m_event.WaitOne();
      Console.WriteLine("Signal received from main");
   }).Start();

   Console.WriteLine("Sending signal");
   Thread.Sleep(1000);
   m_event.Set();

   m_event.Dispose();
}
```

If you wanted to re-use the event, it is automatically reset to blocking after `Set()` is called because we are using an `AutoResetEvent`. With `ManualResetEvent` you would need to call `Reset()` in order to have it block threads again.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out. Should the _WriteCompleted.Dispose()_ also be within the brackets in _using_?

Comment: @Naz `using` blocks call `Dispose()` automatically when an object goes out of scope. If you don't have the event in a using block (which you probably won't) then you need to call `Dispose()` explicitly. I added a more concrete example.

Comment: I create a _new AutoResetEvent_ as you said in the _public myClass_. Then, _myFunction()_ is called from _myThread()_, both of which are also inside _myClass_. The _event.set()_ is inside _myFunction()_, but for some reason it does not have the _.Dispose()_ filed, so I used _.Close()_ filed. In addition, when I run the application, it throws an "_unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Safe handle has been closed_". Do you know what I did wrong?

Comment: @Naz Well, the exception says "Handle has been closed". I'm going to guess it means that you tried to use the event again after calling close on it. Just like `CloseHandle` in Win32, you don't want to call `Close()` or `Dispose()` on an object until you are done with it. You should implement `IDisposable` in your `myClass` instead, and dispose the entire class when you're done with it. There is much [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx) on the disposable pattern in C#.